# What custom key bindings should I define to skip lines when adding multiple lines to selection (with CTRL + ALT + Up/Down) in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext2, text-editor, sublimetext

This pertains to Sublime Text 2 editor. I have a piece of code that looks like this : (the pipe `|` character denotes a multiline cursor) :

```
1   CREATE TABLE Apple (
2   id    | INT UNSIGNED    NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT,
3   name  | VARCHAR(50)     UNIQUE, 
4   PRIMARY KEY (id)
5   );
6
7   CREATE TABLE Orange (
8   id    | INT UNSIGNED    NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT,
9   name  | VARCHAR(50)     UNIQUE, 
10  PRIMARY KEY (id)
11  );
```

I'd like to increase indent of the 4 lines where you see the cursor `|` (number 2,3,8,9). I can add lines to selection with `CTRL + ALT + Up/Down` in Sublime Text 2. But how do I skip the lines in between i.e. number 4,5,7. ?

Update : The actual code has 100s of lines of code. Hence looking for an easy solution, preferably without the mouse.

**Update 2 :** Seems like it isn't possible with the current key-mapping. But can it be done by defining a custom keyboard shortcut? I know the key-bindings file. What should I add there to be able to skip line selection while doing a series of `CTRL + ALT + Up/Down`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CTRL + CLICK` allows for multiple placement of your cursor, so you could `CTRL + CLICK` everywhere you want to indent, then hit tab.

Comment: At first I thought it worked but when I use CTRL+ALT+Up/Down after CTRL+Click, it breaks. I have 100s of lines to simply go clicking everywhere.

Comment: @buffer Gotcha, well, maybe someone else knows, I have run into this problem myself, but never found a satisfactory solution. Good luck!

Comment: @buffer Not a full solution, because it does use the mouse, but you can use `CTRL + DRAG` with the mouse to select blocks of separated code.

Comment: Agreed, but its a drag :)

Answer (score 1):

You can perform a find and replace (`Ctrl + H`) and use regex matching. Take your matched capture buffer (`$1` or `\1`) and add indention to it in the replace field needed. Regexes should be flexible enough to meet your needs, as you can match text and whitespace (or lack thereof).

Comment: Find What: ^(id|name)  Replace With: \t\1     Also, don't forget to enable regex.

Comment: The strength of sublime text is "keyboard shortcuts" for all kinds of whiz-bang scenarios. Regex is a fallback if that fails. I'd really love to use a shortcut even if its custom defined for this purpose. I use it often enough.

Answer (score 1):

I'll tell you about one approach, that uses only keyboard.

Select the first line: (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>l</kbd>)

```
id    | INT UNSIGNED    NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> multiple times

now use the arrow keys to set the cursor position between the variable name and type, and press space 4 times.

repeat for the second line. (of course it works only in the case all structures are equal).